# Linklist operator overload doesn't print out what I want

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I'm implementing a linkedlist with operator overload.  The
code should have printed out `A B` but, instead, it printed out `A`. I have
implemented this code to be able to add list element using the `+` and `-`
operators. But the result is not as I wanted. What's the problem with it?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class listNode{
    public:
        listNode* next;
        listNode* previous;
        char    data;
        listNode(char data):data(data){};
};
class LinkedList{
    public:
        listNode* head=nullptr;
        listNode* end=nullptr;
        int listPush(char data){
            listNode* tmp=new listNode(data);
            if(end==nullptr && head==nullptr){
                end=head=tmp;
                end->next=nullptr;
                end->previous=nullptr;
            }
            else{
                end->next=tmp;
                tmp->previous=end;
                end=tmp;
                end->next=nullptr;
            }
            return 0;

        }
        int listAddNode(listNode data){
             if(end==nullptr && head==nullptr)
                end=head=&data;
            else{
                end->next=&data;
                (&data)->previous=end;
                end=&data;
                end->next=nullptr;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        listNode* listPop(){
            listNode* tmp;
            if(end==nullptr && head==nullptr)
                return nullptr;
            else if(head==end){
                tmp=head;
                head=end=nullptr;
                return tmp;
            }
            else
            {
                tmp=end;
                end=end->previous;
                end->next=nullptr;
                return tmp;
            }
        }
        int  printlist(){
            listNode *tmp=head;
            for(tmp;tmp!=nullptr;tmp=tmp->next)
                cout<<tmp->data<<' ';
            cout<<endl;
        } 
        int  operator+ (char const & data){
                return listPush(data);
        };
         int  operator- (char const & data){
                listNode *tmp=end;
                for(tmp;tmp!=nullptr;tmp=tmp->previous){
                    if(data==tmp->data && tmp==end){
                        if(end==head){
                            this->head=this->end=nullptr;
                            delete tmp;
                            break;
                        }

                        tmp->previous->next=nullptr;
                        end=tmp->previous;
                        delete tmp;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(data==head->data && tmp==head){
                        tmp->next->previous=nullptr;
                        head=head->next;
                        delete tmp;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(data==tmp->data){
                        tmp->previous->next=tmp->next;
                        tmp->next->previous=tmp->previous;
                        delete tmp;
                        break;
                    }


                }

        }


};
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    LinkedList test;
    test+'A'+'B';
    test.printlist();

    return 0;
}
```

In the `main` function I add 'A' and 'B' to test but it still don't even show B. If I add it respectively than the result will be as what I want. I don't know what's wrong. Please help me.

Comment: You arithmetic operators `+` and `-` makes no sense. `test + 'A' + 'B'` is equal to `(test + 'A') + 'B'`, and it will not append `'B'` to the list. Please see e.g. [this binary operator canonical implementation reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Binary_arithmetic_operators) to see what the operator functions should return.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

This function

```
    int listAddNode(listNode data){
         if(end==nullptr && head==nullptr)
            end=head=&data;
        else{
            end->next=&data;
            (&data)->previous=end;
            end=&data;
            end->next=nullptr;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

invokes undefined behavior because the pointer end will point to a local variable data of the function that will not be alive after exiting the function.

Also pay attention to that as the operator

```
    int  operator+ (char const & data){
            return listPush(data);
    };
```

returns int then this statement

```
test+'A'+'B';
```

does not make sense.

It would be better to declare the operator `+=` For example

```
    LinkedList & operator +=( char const & data );
```

Comment: It makes sense. It adds `'A'` to the list `test`, which returns 0. Then it adds `'B'` to 0, which results in `'B'` (the number 66).

Comment: @user253751 If something yields a result it does not mean that it makes a sense.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in original implementation

```
test+'A'+'B';
```

pushes 'A' to test, returns 0 and then adds 0+'B', resulting again in 'B' (see also  [user253751](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60168522/linklist-operator-overload-doesnt-print-out-what-i-want#comment106422759_60168616)) and then discarding this result 'B'. Final result is that test contains only 'A' and test.printlist(); prints only 'A'.

Technically it could be fixed by definition:

```
LinkedList operator+ (char const& data) {
    listPush (data);
    return *this;
  };
```

But better redesign following reference by [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60168522/linklist-operator-overload-doesnt-print-out-what-i-want#comment106420674_60168522) and [Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60168616/7163942)